# Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am migrating a Cosmos DB SQL API to Cosmos DB Mongo API.

In the Cosmos DB SQL API, I have Stored Procedures. I am not seeing this option in the Cosmos DB Mongo API in the Portal.

In the application, we are using this stored procedure.

Is there any option, to put the stored Procedures in the Cosmos DB Mongo API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures are only applicable to Cosmos DB's SQL API. You'll need to implement your logic from your calling application, or tailor your queries to take advantage of the MongoDB capabilities.